# Set builder notation: Why don't use just the condition to define sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Why don't use just the condition to define sets?. Using Set-Builder notation, first we define the variable and later the conditions to be met. But, isn't redundant?. Why don't just get rid of declaring the variable and explicitly say the conditions that already include the variable itself?.

e.g.

$\{x∣p(x)\}$ why not $\{p(x)\}$?

Comment: Because $p(x)$ in $\{ p(x) \}$ express a property that may hold or not. It's not a single object. Having said that, it is a convention; the formula used to express the condition may have other variables.

Comment: Something similar is actually done in probability theory: Formally, the probability that a random variable $X$ is larger than $a$ is $P[\{\omega~\vert~X(\omega)>a\}]$. But it's often shortened to $P[X(\omega)>a]$, or even just $P[X>a]$.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA. So, you define the object then the property to be met, right?. You can not define the set with the property alone without defining first the object. Am I right?

Comment: How would you write $\{x+e^x : x \in \mathbb{N}\} $ ?

Comment: Not exactly: you have a "universe" of objects, e.g. natural numbers. You use a property $p(x)$ to "carve out" from the universe the set of all and only those objects that satisfy the property $\{ n \mid n \in \mathbb N \text { and } n \text { is Even } \}$

Comment: See e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659612/is-there-a-semantics-of-set-builder-notation)

Comment: I could write the set of "all men such that men wear red" or just the set of all "men wearing red". I imagine it like this: Bigger circle cointains all men and inside it an inner smaller circle "men who wear red". You can build the set saying: all in the bigger circle such that inner circle property or say all men in the inner circle. Or not? @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry for asking too much, but this soul needs answers and you are my only way to clear them away at the moment.

Comment: Correct; the set of all "men wearing red" will be $\{ x \mid \text {Man}(x) \text { and  WearRed}(x) \}$